# How do I return a divStr properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I currently have a function that takes 2 inputs and a divStr

```js
function showallnick(){
  let list = [" the Pianist ", " the Scientist ", " the Coder ", " the Student ", " Sleepy "];
  let first = firstInEl.value;
  let last = lastInEl.value;
  let divStr = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    divStr += `<div> ${list[i]}</div>`;
  }
  nicknameEl.innerHTML = allNickname(first, divStr, last);
}
```

But when I return it

```js
function allNickname (f, d, l){
  return f + d + l
}
```

The return function shows up like this:

```
First 
divStr
divStr
Last
```

instead of

```
First divStr Last
First divStr Last
First divStr Last
First divStr Last
```

What is the problem with the return function?

Comment: try an inline `<span>` instead of a block-element `<div>`

Comment: What's inside `list` ?

Comment: @Samathingamajig 

let list = [" the Pianist ", " the Scientist ", " the Coder ", " the Student ", " Sleepy "];

Comment: Why do you expect `f + d + l` to result in `f + d + l + f + d + l + f + d + l + f + d + l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to use `allNickname` on each element of `list`.

```js
function showallnick(){
  let list = [" the Pianist ", " the Scientist ", " the Coder ", " the Student ", " Sleepy "];
  let first = firstInEl.value;
  let last = lastInEl.value;
  let divStr = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    divStr += `<div>${allNickname(first, list[i], last)}</div>`;
  }
  nicknameEl.innerHTML = divStr;
}
```

Here's a full version with that implemented:

```js
function showallnick(){
  let list = [" the Pianist ", " the Scientist ", " the Coder ", " the Student ", " Sleepy "];
  let first = firstInEl.value;
  let last = lastInEl.value;
  let divStr = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    divStr += `<div>${allNickname(first, list[i], last)}</div>`;
  }
  nicknameEl.innerHTML = divStr;
}

function allNickname (f, d, l){
  return f + d + l
}
```

```html
<input id="firstInEl" placeholder="first" />
<input id="lastInEl" placeholder="last" />

<button onclick="showallnick()">showallnick()</button>

<div id="nicknameEl"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function functionOne(){
  let first = firstInEl.value;
  let last = lastInEl.value;
  let divStr = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    divStr += `<div> ${first} ${list[i]} ${last}</div> \n`;
  }
   nicknameEl.innerHTML = allNickname(divStr);
   console.log(allNickname(divStr))
}

function allNickname (d){
  return d;
}
```

Comment: @Sant Simple solution was to add first and last variable inside the divStr , ` divStr += "${first}  String  ${last} "`